# While storing java objects into DB we are getting checksum fail issue. There is no issue in database. need prompt assistance

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

> 019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2019-11-20
>   07:52:13.296 WARN 34 --- [nio-8080-exec-6]
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection : HikariPool-1 - Connection
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@24fb32ea marked as broken because of
>   SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002) 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error:
>   Checksum fail 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11190)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0] 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:244)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar!/:12.1.0.1.0] 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:128)
>   ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
>   [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar!/:na] 2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30
>   [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:119)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:105)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:212)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:633)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1453)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:510)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3282)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2478)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]
>   2019-11-20T13:22:13.296+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
>   [hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar!/:5.3.9.Final]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue on that particular version of the Oracle JDBC drver. To fix it, you can do one of the following:

- Update to a newer version (e.g: 12.2.0.1)
- Set the following parameters: `-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1` with the current version of driver

Comment: Where do we need to set this parameter(-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED-Doracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1) in springboot application, Could you please assist

Comment: You should pass them as arguments to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

How do you connect to the database ?
By context.xml ?
If so here is what you need todo

```
<Resource name="jdbc/a_NAME" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="... and other props"
connectionProperties="oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED;oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1;"/>
```

If you are using spring jpa appplication yaml file

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: ...
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        tomcat:
          connection-properties: oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client=REQUIRED;oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client=SHA1;
```